# animate the js .scrollLeft property

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, transition

I'm working on a carousel slider and change the [element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) property based on a calculation, triggered on click events.

The manipulation of the scrollLeft property works fine but I have problems to implement a transition between the initial scrollLeft value and the new value. I only found solutions for jQuery. Is there an obvious solution I overlooked or do I need to use an package for an animated transition?

Thanks for you help.